# Accessing data to display as search results in Android app

Tags: java, android, database, google-maps

I am developing an Android app which takes the current location of the user and displays a list of restaurants close to his/her location. The restaurants' data is available to me (i.e I do have the lat/long of each restaurant I want to display in the search results). I can't use Google Places API, because I need to show only those restaurants that are available in our database(in our website). My question is how do I access my database(or even an URL),which is on a computer, to extract  the restaurants' data and display as search results in my android app?
I am actually making a Seamless ( http://bit.ly/Jp7pUN ) type application for my company.
I am a complete newbie to android app development. So, pardon me if this is really a very broad or a stupid question. Please just tell me what topics I need to study to implement this. I would study and do it myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need:

- a **Sqlite database** to store the restaurants and their longitude/latitude
- a **MapView** to display the map (Don't forget to register your Google Maps **API key**)
- a **map overlay** to show the markers on the map
- **GPS access** to get the user's location (needs the appropriate **Android permission**)
- a simple **search algorithm** that retrieves a result set of restaurants within x distance of the user's location

**EDIT**

If your database is stored on a server, you will need a way to query the server, preferably using an HTTP-based protocol such as **REST**. It is useful (but not required) to **cache** the restaurant locations on the Android device (using Sqlite), in case the user is offline (The good news: Since you can use Java both on Android and the server, 90% of your data access layer you will only need to write once).

For the data transfer from server to the Android client, **JSON** is a popular format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am done with the points 2,3,4. i studied them and have implemented them. But how do I access this database? Through a URL? because this database will only be on a computer or a website.

Comment: ok. so first i need to see how to query the server (using HTTP-based protocol(**REST**)) and then see **JSON** for data  transfer from server database to my app. after that all i need to do is parse the received data appropriately and display my search results.

Answer (score 1):

To acces database on your computer (not SQLite on Android) you should use url for your database server changing `localhost` to: 10.0.2.2. But in case your database will be on the Internet - you should create maybe some REST API to get the data you need. Then use `HttpClient` to fetch the data from server.

Everything that you need is in [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html): [MapView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)
And for retrieving current location I advice using `MyLocationOverlay`

For example (url to server):

```
//public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:3000"; // for localhost server
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://railsserver.herokuapp.com"; //for remote server
```

Accessing data on your server - this depends on that how you implement (and using what thechnology) your server (REST API?, WebService?, Plain HTML?) and what will be the format of the response from server (JSON? XML?, etc.)

I suggest using JSON because it is easy to parse using included classes in Android SDK:

```
        String json = execute(new HttpGet(Constants.SERVER_URL + "/fetchData"));
        JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(json);
        if(responseJSON.has("auth_error")) {
            throw new IOException("fetchData_error");
        }
```

Comment: So, i need to use HttpClient to access from a website. and while developing use 10.0.2.2 to access it from my computer. can you suggest me the topic that includes accessing data through url from a website? i have actually implemented the maps part of my app. i just need to know how and from where i access my data from.

Comment: thanks! i will have a look at how to access data from server and probably also use **JSON** as the response format. I do have a lot of research and study to do before I can implement this.